# Install the updated Apk from the same application itself programmatically.[Update apk]

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I am using following code to install an application from my app.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/InstallTest.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Let the package for above code is com.xyz.one.
Now if I install any other package application with the mentioned code then it works fine.
But if I try the same code for the updated apk version of the same application i.e. com.xyz.one then it gives "There is a problem parsing the package".

Someone please help how can I install the apk programmatically from the same application itself.

Note: My update apk is present in external storage.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried installing apk manually?

Comment: @DhavalPatel yes manually it is getting installed.

Answer (score 1):

There is so many questions around updating Android Apps via file download and so much has changed that I felt an update would be good at this point so here it is.

The code has been tested on Android O and above and Android N and below and all works!

In the manifest file, to support Android O and above you will need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

and, for accessing the downloaded file you will need:

```
<application
    ...>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/app_installer_path"/>
    </provider>
```

and the referenced XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Since these days many have moved to Kotlin, I'll show that code below:

```
// Plain old filepath: E.g., "/storage/emulated/0/MyAppStorage/Temp/release-1.0.2039.apk"
private lateinit var appUpdateApk: String
```

And the code that does the real work:

```
private fun checkAndroidVersionAndInstallApk() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        if (MyApplication.context.packageManager.canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
            installApk()
        } else {
            startActivityForResult(Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES, Uri.parse("package:${requireContext().packageName}")), INSTALL_PACKAGES_REQUESTCODE)
        }
    } else {
        installApk()
    }
}

private fun installApk() {

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), "${requireContext().packageName}.FileProvider", File(appUpdateApk))
        intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    } else {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(File(appUpdateApk)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

    requireContext().startActivity(intent)
    requireActivity().finish()
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    logInfo("VersionCheckFragment::onActivityResult: $requestCode")

    when (requestCode) {
        INSTALL_PACKAGES_REQUESTCODE -> checkAndroidVersionAndInstallApk()
        else -> {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the action [`ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)?

You can use it to launch the application installer directly and use a few arguments to control the apk file, and the install options.

(`EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME`, `EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE`, `EXTRA_ALLOW_REPLACE`, and `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT`)

Comment: Ya i have already tried this but doesn't seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine for me, I think you may miss the *file://* prefix

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+path ), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have file local in phone or you can download before programmatically :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setDataAndType(
            Uri.fromFile(
                       new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "NameOfFille.apk")
            ), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```