# How to correct update Android .apk?

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

```
    Intent openIntent;
    File file = new File(mApkPath);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        String auth = mContext.getPackageName() + ".file.provider";
        Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, auth, file);
        openIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        openIntent.setData(apkUri);
        openIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        openIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        openIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        openIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        openIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    }
    return openIntent;
```

I found this way can open an Activity which is mean "Install Success" in low SDK version Android device, but in hight SDK version, when install finished, the app will like crash, even if the new .apk was installed.

Have any way to open the activity which is mean "Install Success", so that let user can choose install 'Finished' or 'Open'?

By the way, I got `resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED`, actually, new .apk was installed. And I notice PackageInstaller can user update apk, but how to use it? I read ApiDemos but got `result == PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION` by `int result = intent.getIntExtra(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS, PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE)`, but .apk was Installed and no any 'Finished' or 'Open' button.

Thanks!

Comment: Is their any permission-related problem in higher SDK?

Comment: Yes, how can I correct user it when SDK Version is higher than N?

Comment: I can find an answer, but I need some help. Firstly, I never tried this work. Secondly, I have problem understanding **What type of permission-related problem you're facing?** *Can you post the `logcat`, reproducing the error in the question?*

Comment: If you're using `broadcast receiver` then tell me

Comment: So much has changed over the years, I posted a complete example, working with Android N and below as well as Android O and above here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259488/5890321

Comment: It's my fault, but now I forgot how do I fixed it